# Добавить текст и формы в массив PHP

Tags: php, post, форма

Перепробовала все, видать где-то не понимаю.

Файл INDEX.PHP содержит 4 поля инпут текст и кнопка сабмит

Что я хочу:
Юзер заполнил 4 поля, нажал сабмит и данные отправились в массив. Затем отрисовались на этой же странице из массива.

Юзер второй раз заполнил поля. После нажатия сабмита, данные дописались в массив, вновь отрисовались на странице из массива.

Что получается у меня:
Все нормально выводится, но данные перезаписываются после нажатия на кнопку сабмит. 
 Пробовала **Array_append, array_merge** .

Подскажите алгоритм решения такой проблемы. Данные передаются методом $_POST без action.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сохранять ваш массив в сессию, а при повторном заполнении полей просто сливать массивы функцией array_merge